# How to get dojo.style to appear in firefox

Tags: dojo, coding-style

Hey I was testing this code. The alert displays the result in IE but not in Firefox:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
    <title>Get computed border width</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://o.aolcdn.com/dojo/1.3.2/dojo/dojo.xd.js" djConfig="useXDomain:true">
    </script>
    <script>
        function doOnLoad(){
            var o = dojo.byId("myDiv");
            alert(dojo.getComputedStyle(o).borderWidth);
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body onLoad="doOnLoad();">
    <div style="border-width:10px" id="myDiv">
        I am myDiv
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

What is the reason why the alert is not diplaying in FF?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd advise you to read the API documentation of the function you're using: http://www.dojotoolkit.org/api/dojo.html#dojo.getComputedStyle (note: if the page jumps to the wrong location, focus the address bar and hit enter again.  seems like an unfortunate side-effect currently in the API pages...)

As that says, using `getComputedStyle` directly leaves you at the mercy of the particular browser's implementation of that function.  In the case of `borderWidth`, Gecko appears to automatically expand it to `borderTopWidth` and so-on, subsequently blanking out the value of `borderWidth` itself.

You're probably far more interested in using this instead:

```
dojo.style(o, 'borderWidth')
```

Which will return `10` in both browsers.

Comment: Well that worked. Here is the code:  
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
    <title>Get computed border width</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://o.aolcdn.com/dojo/1.3.2/dojo/dojo.xd.js" djConfig="useXDomain:true">
    </script>
    <script>
        function doOnLoad(){
            var o = dojo.byId("myDiv");
            alert(dojo.style(o, 'borderWidth');
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body onLoad="doOnLoad();">
    <div style="border-width:10px" id="myDiv">
        I am myDiv
    </div>
</body>
</html>